# How does std::cin works?

Tags: c++

I get an int by doing the following:

```
int num;
cin >> num;
```

I get a string by doing the following:

```
string word;
cin >> word;
```

My question is: How does `cin` does the conversion internally? Will it ever output an error if I enter something unexpected? example: "ɔool ʇǝxʇ ƃǝuǝɹɐʇoɹ oulıuǝ". What are the safeguard cin uses?

I'm new to C++

Comment: Have you read any of the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream)?

Comment: It has overloads for the data types you specify.

Comment: And don't forget to look at the language tag infomation. They often have lists of references and FAQs. Very useful stuff! http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `>>` is an operator. C++ provides the ability to define functions that give functionality for any built-in operator. (Note, you cannot create new operators that don't already exist in the language.) In this particular case, the `>>` operator has been overloaded for use with `cin` and either an `int` or a `string`. These functions then carry out the conversion. In the case of the `int` version, it will set an error flag in `cin` if the input cannot be converted to an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

`std::cin` reads from `stdin`.

This:

```
string word;
cin >> word;
```

will return a `string`, not a `char*`. Try avoid char arrays in C++.

Read about `std::cin` [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cin/). Also learning about [stringstreams](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) is very useful when dealing with C++ IO.

Comment: More correctly, `cin` reads from "standard input" (stdin). This may be the console, but it could also be a file or other device depending on the operator system and redirection by the user.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read a book about C++ iostreams. [Like the C++ book by Stroustrup who invented C++.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321958322)

But in summary, a iostream object, like cin, has goodbit, badbit, failbit and eofbit. [Look at iostate.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base)

The cin object will return false when it is anything but good. So you can read integers like this:

```
int my_int;
while(cin >> my_int) {
    cout << "Received " << my_int << "\n";
}
```

The loop will exit when it reads anything that isn't a number or when it reaches the end of file.

Comment: "The cin object will return false when it is anything but good" To be pedantic, `operator>>` will return the stream itself, not a boolean. Fortunately, the stream has a (an eventual) conversion to `bool` based on whether the goodbit is set or not.